# How can we transform energy conservation laws on inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, coordinate-systems, vectors

Suppose a inclined plane [image: figure of inclined plane]
Now in normal projectile problem we can normally apply energy conservation laws but in this case since this is a inclined plane we have to transform the conservation laws now this sounds confusing but i am saying that suppose a ball is thrown from one end of inclined plane and it reaches the other end we can't say that potential energy in both the cases is zero along the inclined plane but suppose we want to make it zero along the inclined plane what transformation we must apply i tried transforming g as components along inclined plane but it didn't work please help me this is not a homework question i am just trying to learn the conversation laws in deep otherwise there are other methods which dont require such transformation

Comment: *"suppose we want to make it zero along the inclined plane"* How can that work? If you put a ball at the top of the incline it will roll down, gaining kinetic energy without losing potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

The change in potential along the incline will be equal to the work done by the component along the incline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what exactly you want, just write the work energy theorem normally. Change in kinetic energy from that will be same as what you calculate from the kinematic equations.